# Decode string with PKC7 in Java

Tags: java, string, decode, pkcs#7

I have some `Java` code, and I have a `String` type which includes the following content:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIIzwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIIwDCCCLwCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkq
hkiG9w0BBwGgggZbMIIGVzCCBT+gAwIBAgIELhJ2QDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
mDELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxEDAOBgNVBAoMB1NpZW1lbnMxETAPBgNVBAUTCFpaWlpa
WlkyMTowOAYDVQQLDDFDb3B5cmlnaHQgKEMpIFNpZW1lbnMgQUcgMjAxMyBBbGwg
UmlnaHRzIFJlc2VydmVkMSgwJgYDVQQDDB9TaWVtZW5zIElzc3VpbmcgQ0EgRUUg
QXV0aCAyMDEzMB4XDTE0MDcxODEzNTcwM1oXDTE3MDcxODEzNTcwM1owYzERMA8G
A1UEBRMIWjAwMzBBTUgxDzANBgNVBCoMBkFsZXhleTERMA8GA1UEBAwIU2Vkb3lr
aW4xEDAOBgNVBAoMB1NpZW1lbnMxGDAWBgNVBAMMD1NlZG95a2luIEFsZXhleTCC
ASAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQEBA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCKahNgWzDPSnOwba2ljWQb8Lni
uvAGZHEvdd5zm8H7Kw56WMxdixKHoKSChXWf1zGE3RZAsQOdHOpcgiqnRF2xLe2l
LjCLoE9sC4DfUVD4mKe3kcxtnsxkoLc1A/3QXJSOzpk7rPJeqehmuj06yCtPjpdF
Gmtf4bkskiQuK8u4RJfnmzffWQppd2Ld+u8tLxQKyHnZtOnPyYQGRQJXJKhruDnn
LonlveVXKzEzmo88E5udB+/6jDWDfuyfKHMFyOhk80qGeYDOYQHxiq/PJbAyQU6X
PONbfsCgILKxx7uHaBlhNALxjFZSeNNtfg0bx82O1DoJEcWcOjZQtQMuNUjvAgMB
AAGjggLdMIIC2TAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUE5jDSnfWWnlUWMKztQ6zYfgohUkwUwYDVR0R
BEwwSqArBgorBgEEAYI3FAIDoB0MG2FsZXhleS5zZWRveWtpbkBzaWVtZW5zLmNv
bYEbYWxleGV5LnNlZG95a2luQHNpZW1lbnMuY29tMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDCC
AQQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBIH3MIH0MDIGCCsGAQUFBzAChiZodHRwOi8vYWguc2llbWVu
cy5jb20vcGtpP1paWlpaWlkyLmNydDBBBggrBgEFBQcwAoY1bGRhcDovL2FsLnNp
ZW1lbnMubmV0L0NOPVpaWlpaWlkyLEw9UEtJP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwSQYIKwYB
BQUHMAKGPWxkYXA6Ly9hbC5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbS9DTj1aWlpaWlpZMixvPVRydXN0
Y2VudGVyP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwMAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGJGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnBr
aS1zZXJ2aWNlcy5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTelD9Lal9YThQYyUbX
FDnCnCE8KTAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMBoGA1UdIAQTMBEwDwYNKwYBBAGhaQcCAgMB
ATCBygYDVR0fBIHCMIG/MIG8oIG5oIG2hiZodHRwOi8vY2guc2llbWVucy5jb20v
cGtpP1paWlpaWlkyLmNybIZBbGRhcDovL2NsLnNpZW1lbnMubmV0L0NOPVpaWlpa
WlkyLEw9UEtJP2NlcnRpZmljYXRlUmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3SGSWxkYXA6Ly9jbC5z
aWVtZW5zLmNvbS9DTj1aWlpaWlpZMixvPVRydXN0Y2VudGVyP2NlcnRpZmljYXRl
UmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3QwMwYDVR0lBCwwKgYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEBgor
BgEEAYI3FAICBggrBgEFBQgCAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAmzrYxmkRuSPM
itK0rnR98BXlnB88ldVXjyz+rjHg9QghoZ5+8u7wHnxMSXida4XvYbhN5maUQs3D
dWebvXP6CXt/OErVgYHlEAT8d5iqvin7/6eEgS0ge9DOxD2Rv+LYltPmAsjgxUS/
0MecbUJpyBct6mDNfPI7riCu+mCcw6v9OKLWnXTIZsV9Z/WqaFbqVeJ5wo1+MUGW
CGrDVkn7XnCKAQN8xEEO+Dq/TSVyv8tlDUzWps1yb3l9cYDc030s5AwFXa99v76p
YJUZ08qQsieXOrs3qyQxMalM/Y042N17bwf9XkGT6iKN8o8U0YS1Vkaz8iroBRKk
iA2pRNN4AjGCAjgwggI0AgEBMIGhMIGYMQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEQMA4GA1UECgwH
U2llbWVuczERMA8GA1UEBRMIWlpaWlpaWTIxOjA4BgNVBAsMMUNvcHlyaWdodCAo
QykgU2llbWVucyBBRyAyMDEzIEFsbCBSaWdodHMgUmVzZXJ2ZWQxKDAmBgNVBAMM
H1NpZW1lbnMgSXNzdWluZyBDQSBFRSBBdXRoIDIwMTMCBC4SdkAwDQYJYIZIAWUD
BAIBBQCgaTAYBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEP
Fw0xNzA1MDMxNDI3NTFaMC8GCSqGSIb3DQEJBDEiBCBCA/fR9wGftKzKFZRuIDJV
bYiaHzsDteoUoUL55kMrYDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAQA6HtP3xr36VLj+WMao
PRrszLfMJTE7lKIX3Vjybj2W3yj4qanPamZBb4KyEDIvQA8r65j4dbzcDePoFsRB
5eYRnfB/djuXPAZdL9xdFMH3iRzfcseSFXulZ8FrG/9cuqDQkYVIx/Fk43yLtlpx
OncVG3vZVW306yKQLu7Tsy+/GEkNDBMt6akqNPWp+9zqQTj7TaCXg7qr7mTlSStZ
E15USoAOelisALpwPdizvfaJOqP03IobwDXMfRaCjzEANVl/M3woL1sNLu6BtuMe
mAdls8tnJWDF+wpD4Y256Dso4FvDe2iK923jNElzq4iyc6ZosqGORS3nTh/1FQyp
gkC1
-----END PKCS7-----
```

How can I convert this `String` into a readable state?

So far, I've used the following website just to test: https://certlogik.com/decoder/

Comment: What do you mean with "readable state"? I think the URL that you provided is already doing what you expected, correct me if wrong.

Comment: @OscarJara thank you for response! Yes, it does, but I need to implement such behavior in my Java application

Comment: All the information like the website shows or just a part of it? on the other hand, what have you tried? could be cool if you share it.

Comment: @OscarJara in first approach - all information, i tried use BouncyCastle, also i saw any topics with similar tasks on Stake Overflow, but unfortunately i not a programmer:(

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest to use that library, let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, even if you never posted an approach showing us what you've tried before for achieving your task and even if you said that you are not a programmer *(I wonder how are you going to understand then).*

I wanted to play around with this and this is what I got so far...

---

### Notes

Since you are new to this, consider the following:

- Use ***bouncycastle*** library within your project, include the `bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar` file to the Build Path.
- In order to use ***bouncycastle*** library, you'll need the "Java Cryptography Extension" JARs and, in order to do so, replace the `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` files located at `C:\path\to\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security` with the ones from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

*(the link will download a ZIP file with the JARs for Java 7 since I am using that version, you should download the right ones for the Java version that you are using)*.

### Project structure

Just created a simple Java Project and defined this structure:

[image]

### Java code

Things to consider...

- There are many attributes to obtain from the certificate and getting some of them are a bit tricky (you'll need to do some research here in order to get them all, same way as: https://certlogik.com/decoder/ currently does).
- I've changed the header/footer: `BEGIN PKCS7/END PKCS7` from the certificate, because of the following: http://openssl.cs.utah.edu/docs/apps/pkcs7.html (read under "Notes" section) and because the certificate `String` can't be parsed as a `X509Certificate` object when not using the other ones, which are: `BEGIN CERTIFICATE/END CERTIFICATE`. Also, something that I noticed was that after decoding the certificate on the website that you provided, the `BEGIN PKCS7/END PKCS7` header/footer are replaced in your certificate `String` with the other ones that I was talking about before.

Obtained from above link:

> The PEM PKCS#7 format uses the header and footer lines:
>
> -----BEGIN PKCS7-----
>    -----END PKCS7-----
>
> For compatibility with some CAs it will also accept:
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>    -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Then, here goes the runnable Java class:

```
package com.cert.example.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader;

public class CertificateDecoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String certStr = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" + 
                "MIIIzwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIIwDCCCLwCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkq\r\n" + 
                "hkiG9w0BBwGgggZbMIIGVzCCBT+gAwIBAgIELhJ2QDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB\r\n" + 
                "mDELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxEDAOBgNVBAoMB1NpZW1lbnMxETAPBgNVBAUTCFpaWlpa\r\n" + 
                "WlkyMTowOAYDVQQLDDFDb3B5cmlnaHQgKEMpIFNpZW1lbnMgQUcgMjAxMyBBbGwg\r\n" + 
                "UmlnaHRzIFJlc2VydmVkMSgwJgYDVQQDDB9TaWVtZW5zIElzc3VpbmcgQ0EgRUUg\r\n" + 
                "QXV0aCAyMDEzMB4XDTE0MDcxODEzNTcwM1oXDTE3MDcxODEzNTcwM1owYzERMA8G\r\n" + 
                "A1UEBRMIWjAwMzBBTUgxDzANBgNVBCoMBkFsZXhleTERMA8GA1UEBAwIU2Vkb3lr\r\n" + 
                "aW4xEDAOBgNVBAoMB1NpZW1lbnMxGDAWBgNVBAMMD1NlZG95a2luIEFsZXhleTCC\r\n" + 
                "ASAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQEBA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCKahNgWzDPSnOwba2ljWQb8Lni\r\n" + 
                "uvAGZHEvdd5zm8H7Kw56WMxdixKHoKSChXWf1zGE3RZAsQOdHOpcgiqnRF2xLe2l\r\n" + 
                "LjCLoE9sC4DfUVD4mKe3kcxtnsxkoLc1A/3QXJSOzpk7rPJeqehmuj06yCtPjpdF\r\n" + 
                "Gmtf4bkskiQuK8u4RJfnmzffWQppd2Ld+u8tLxQKyHnZtOnPyYQGRQJXJKhruDnn\r\n" + 
                "LonlveVXKzEzmo88E5udB+/6jDWDfuyfKHMFyOhk80qGeYDOYQHxiq/PJbAyQU6X\r\n" + 
                "PONbfsCgILKxx7uHaBlhNALxjFZSeNNtfg0bx82O1DoJEcWcOjZQtQMuNUjvAgMB\r\n" + 
                "AAGjggLdMIIC2TAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUE5jDSnfWWnlUWMKztQ6zYfgohUkwUwYDVR0R\r\n" + 
                "BEwwSqArBgorBgEEAYI3FAIDoB0MG2FsZXhleS5zZWRveWtpbkBzaWVtZW5zLmNv\r\n" + 
                "bYEbYWxleGV5LnNlZG95a2luQHNpZW1lbnMuY29tMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDCC\r\n" + 
                "AQQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBIH3MIH0MDIGCCsGAQUFBzAChiZodHRwOi8vYWguc2llbWVu\r\n" + 
                "cy5jb20vcGtpP1paWlpaWlkyLmNydDBBBggrBgEFBQcwAoY1bGRhcDovL2FsLnNp\r\n" + 
                "ZW1lbnMubmV0L0NOPVpaWlpaWlkyLEw9UEtJP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwSQYIKwYB\r\n" + 
                "BQUHMAKGPWxkYXA6Ly9hbC5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbS9DTj1aWlpaWlpZMixvPVRydXN0\r\n" + 
                "Y2VudGVyP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwMAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGJGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnBr\r\n" + 
                "aS1zZXJ2aWNlcy5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTelD9Lal9YThQYyUbX\r\n" + 
                "FDnCnCE8KTAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMBoGA1UdIAQTMBEwDwYNKwYBBAGhaQcCAgMB\r\n" + 
                "ATCBygYDVR0fBIHCMIG/MIG8oIG5oIG2hiZodHRwOi8vY2guc2llbWVucy5jb20v\r\n" + 
                "cGtpP1paWlpaWlkyLmNybIZBbGRhcDovL2NsLnNpZW1lbnMubmV0L0NOPVpaWlpa\r\n" + 
                "WlkyLEw9UEtJP2NlcnRpZmljYXRlUmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3SGSWxkYXA6Ly9jbC5z\r\n" + 
                "aWVtZW5zLmNvbS9DTj1aWlpaWlpZMixvPVRydXN0Y2VudGVyP2NlcnRpZmljYXRl\r\n" + 
                "UmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3QwMwYDVR0lBCwwKgYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEBgor\r\n" + 
                "BgEEAYI3FAICBggrBgEFBQgCAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAmzrYxmkRuSPM\r\n" + 
                "itK0rnR98BXlnB88ldVXjyz+rjHg9QghoZ5+8u7wHnxMSXida4XvYbhN5maUQs3D\r\n" + 
                "dWebvXP6CXt/OErVgYHlEAT8d5iqvin7/6eEgS0ge9DOxD2Rv+LYltPmAsjgxUS/\r\n" + 
                "0MecbUJpyBct6mDNfPI7riCu+mCcw6v9OKLWnXTIZsV9Z/WqaFbqVeJ5wo1+MUGW\r\n" + 
                "CGrDVkn7XnCKAQN8xEEO+Dq/TSVyv8tlDUzWps1yb3l9cYDc030s5AwFXa99v76p\r\n" + 
                "YJUZ08qQsieXOrs3qyQxMalM/Y042N17bwf9XkGT6iKN8o8U0YS1Vkaz8iroBRKk\r\n" + 
                "iA2pRNN4AjGCAjgwggI0AgEBMIGhMIGYMQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEQMA4GA1UECgwH\r\n" + 
                "U2llbWVuczERMA8GA1UEBRMIWlpaWlpaWTIxOjA4BgNVBAsMMUNvcHlyaWdodCAo\r\n" + 
                "QykgU2llbWVucyBBRyAyMDEzIEFsbCBSaWdodHMgUmVzZXJ2ZWQxKDAmBgNVBAMM\r\n" + 
                "H1NpZW1lbnMgSXNzdWluZyBDQSBFRSBBdXRoIDIwMTMCBC4SdkAwDQYJYIZIAWUD\r\n" + 
                "BAIBBQCgaTAYBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEP\r\n" + 
                "Fw0xNzA1MDMxNDI3NTFaMC8GCSqGSIb3DQEJBDEiBCBCA/fR9wGftKzKFZRuIDJV\r\n" + 
                "bYiaHzsDteoUoUL55kMrYDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAQA6HtP3xr36VLj+WMao\r\n" + 
                "PRrszLfMJTE7lKIX3Vjybj2W3yj4qanPamZBb4KyEDIvQA8r65j4dbzcDePoFsRB\r\n" + 
                "5eYRnfB/djuXPAZdL9xdFMH3iRzfcseSFXulZ8FrG/9cuqDQkYVIx/Fk43yLtlpx\r\n" + 
                "OncVG3vZVW306yKQLu7Tsy+/GEkNDBMt6akqNPWp+9zqQTj7TaCXg7qr7mTlSStZ\r\n" + 
                "E15USoAOelisALpwPdizvfaJOqP03IobwDXMfRaCjzEANVl/M3woL1sNLu6BtuMe\r\n" + 
                "mAdls8tnJWDF+wpD4Y256Dso4FvDe2iK923jNElzq4iyc6ZosqGORS3nTh/1FQyp\r\n" + 
                "gkC1\r\n" + 
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

        // Init bouncycastle
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // Get certificate
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(certStr);
        PEMReader pr = new PEMReader(sr);
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)pr.readObject();
        pr.close();

        // Get Public Key as RSA in order to get extra attributes
        RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey)cert.getPublicKey();

        System.out.println(printCertInfo(cert, rsaPublicKey));
    }

    static String printCertInfo(X509Certificate cert, RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("Certificate:\r\n");
        sb.append("Data:\r\n");
        sb.append("\tVersion: " + cert.getVersion() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tSerial Number: " + cert.getSerialNumber() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tSignature Algorithm: " + cert.getSigAlgName() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tIssuer: " + cert.getIssuerDN().getName() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tSignature Algorithm: " + cert.getSigAlgName() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tValidity\r\n");
        sb.append("\t\tNot Before: " + cert.getNotBefore() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\t\tNot After: " + cert.getNotAfter() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tSubject: " + cert.getSubjectDN() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\tSubject Public Key Info:\r\n");
        sb.append("\t\tPublic Key Algorithm: " + rsaPublicKey.getAlgorithm() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\t\t\tPublic-Key: " + rsaPublicKey.getModulus().bitLength() + " bit \r\n");
        sb.append("\t\t\tModulus:\r\n");
        sb.append("\t\t\t\t" + rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toString(16) + "\r\n");
        sb.append("\t\t\tExponent: " + rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent() + "\r\n");

        // TODO: Print other attributes, do some research to get them all...

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

### Output

If I get the time, I'll try to get all the attributes, same way as the website that you provided does. Right now, the code from above will output the following:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3
    Serial Number: 772961856
    Signature Algorithm: SHA1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=DE,O=Siemens,SERIALNUMBER=ZZZZZZY2,OU=Copyright (C) Siemens AG 2013 All Rights Reserved,CN=Siemens Issuing CA EE Auth 2013
    Signature Algorithm: SHA1WithRSAEncryption
    Validity
        Not Before: Fri Jul 18 09:57:03 EDT 2014
        Not After: Tue Jul 18 09:57:03 EDT 2017
    Subject: SERIALNUMBER=Z0030AMH,GIVENNAME=Alexey,SURNAME=Sedoykin,O=Siemens,CN=Sedoykin Alexey
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: RSA
            Public-Key: 2048 bit 
            Modulus:
                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
            Exponent: 65537
```

Comment: You don't need Bouncy for this; by hacking the label to CERTIFICATE when it isn't  you caused PEMReader (from 2011 and obsolete) to call CertificateFactory, which handles _both_ certificate _and_ PKCS7-SignedData. You can get the same result calling CertificateFactory directly on the PKCS7. Also, unlimited-policy was never required by Bouncy as such, but for symmetric over 128 bits in _either_ standard provider(s) _or_ Bouncy; this example doesn't do symmetric and doesn't need it. (Subsequently in fall 2017 unlimited-policy was removed entirely.)