# Decode string with PKC7 in Java?

Tags: java, string, decode, pkcs#7

There is the same question here:
[Decode string with PKC7 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945101/decode-string-with-pkc7-in-java)
I tried the solution described there, but obviously it is a little outdated, because in the current bouncycastle library there is no
org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader
class, but
org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser.
and when i used it in the example:

```
        PEMParser pr = new PEMParser(sr);
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)pr.readObject();
```

i got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo cannot be cast to class java.security.cert.X509Certificate
```

I would like just to ask someone to provide solution of decoding PKCS#7 with the current Bouncycastle library.

The Maven part for Bouncycastle looks like this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.58</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the PKCS#7 that i am trying to decode:

```
 -----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
```

Answer (score 1):

PKCS7 and its successor CMS is a wide-ranging standard that includes many types of messages. *Some* of these messages can contain one or more (X.509) certificate(s). *If* your PKCS7/CMS is actually a SignedData containing certificate(s), you don't need BouncyCastle at all; you can directly read the certificate(s) with standard Java `CertificateFactory` as described in the introductory section of [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html).

That is actually what the hacky code in the Q you link does; by putting a false PEM label of BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE on data that is in fact NOT a certificate, but actually a PKCS7/CMS SignedData *containing* a certificate, it causes the now-obsolete PEMReader code to call CertificateFactory internally. With more recent PEMParser that wouldn't work; you must parse it as PKCS7/CMS and then resolve it yourself. (Even 1.58 isn't exactly current, it's from 2017.) If you want to go that way, the following example reads the data from that Q (correctly labelled as BEGIN/END PKCS7, NOT faked as CERTIFICATE) and extracts the one cert:

```
    String in = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0])) );
    // import org.bouncycastle.asn1.* and ...cms.* (not superseded ...pkcs.*)
    // and of course org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser 
    @SuppressWarnings("resource") // I don't bother closing the PEMParser
    ContentInfo ci = (ContentInfo) new PEMParser(new StringReader(in)).readObject();
    if( !ci.getContentType().equals(CMSObjectIdentifiers.signedData) ) 
        throw new Exception ("not SignedData"); // or other handling as suitable
    SignedData sd = SignedData.getInstance( ci.getContent() );
    // this takes the first/only cert and fails if none; could handle missing
    // and/or loop over multiple looking for or selecting the desired one or ones
    byte[] raw = ((ASN1Sequence)sd.getCertificates().getObjects().nextElement()) .getEncoded();
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
            .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw));
    System.out.println (cert.toString());
```

Numerous variations are possible depending on exactly what you need to handle.

Note SignedData.certs is an ASN.1 SET and arbitrarily ordered. If used for e.g. a rootlist this doesn't matter, but if used for a cert *chain* -- as many CAs did in ancient times -- the end-entity or 'leaf' cert, although logically first in the chain, may not be physically first in the PKCS7/CMS. In recent years CAs more often just use a sequence of (individual) PEM certs, which does preserve order -- and which CertificateFactory and keytool etc *also* handles.

---

Added: you now disclose you (also?) want the certificate *in PEM form* (the textlike form beginning `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ending `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`). This is trivial with Bouncy; just do

```
JcaPEMWriter w = new JcaPEMWriter (/*suitable Writer to a file or whatever */)
w.writeObject(cert); 
w.close(); // or w.flush(); to keep underlying writer/stream open
```

or if you only need the PEM and aren't doing anything cryptoish with the cert object, more simply

```
PemWriter w = new PemWriter (/*suitable Writer as above */);
w.writeObject (new PemObject ("CERTIFICATE",raw)); 
w.close(); // ditto
```

For the standard-Java case you must do some of the work yourself:

```
// create or obtain a suitable Writer to file or whatever as w
w.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" + eol
    + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(cert.getEncoded()) + eol
    + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" + eol);
// w.flush() or w.close() if needed depending on the Writer

// or for a PrintStream (like System.out) optionally like
p.println("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
p.write(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode(cert.getEncoded());
p.println(); 
p.println("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

// in principle eol should be appropriate for your output
// e.g. System.getProperty("line.separator") for a local file
// but possibly different for data sent someplace else;
// in practice PEM data usually works with either CRLF or LF 
// on _all_ systems (and if not are usually easy to fix)

// _some_ systems even accept the base64 on one unbroken line
// as from Base64.getEncoder() rather than .getMimeEncoder() 
// but I wouldn't suggest relying on that, it is nonstandard
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I posted the PKCS#7, that i am trying to decode, in the question.
1.With the code from the java documentation i decoded the PKCS7 answer successfully but the certificate itself is not printed. Do you have any idea why and how to do that?
2.With your code and decoding the same PKCS7 i get ClassCastException:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence cannot be cast to class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence
at the line 
'''
byte[] raw = ((DLSequence)sd.getCertificates().getObjects().nextElement()) .getEncoded();
'''

Comment: 1: for me using your newly posted data it prints version, subject, sigalg, key, validity, issuer, serial and extensions -- do you mean/expect something else? 2: I checked and found my IDE was using newer Bouncy than I thought. Changing to superclass ASN1Sequence (or even super^2 ASN1Primitive) works on several versions including 1.58.

Comment: 1. Yes, i would like to see the certificate itself, like on the bottom when posting the PKCS#7 in this site https://certlogik.com/decoder/ (without the BEGIN/END PKCS#7 labels) 2. Ok, i changed to  ASN1Sequence and it worked and i get the same result as 1 :)

Comment: That site is apparently dispalying `openssl x509 -text` output which contains _both_ a field-by-field display _and_ the certificate in PEM format. I assume you mean the latter and added it to the answer.